# Repeating a while loop Python

Tags: python, while-loop

so i am trying to make  this rock paper scissors game, i want to make a while loop that terminates when user input is "quit" but it doesnt seem to work, it either fails to repeat or continues indefinitly, any idea why?

```
import random #this module is used to select randomly one of the three values, rock paper or scissors

words = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
badwords = ["fuck","shit","bitch", "cunt", "fuck off", "piss off", "nigger","motherfucker"]

def check_word_input(word, word_list, bad_word_list=None):
    """
    this function compares the word, in this case user input against a wordlist to see if input is correct, by checking if
    words is present in a wordlist. if not, user is notified that his input is not valid. 
    optionally checks the word against a list of bad words and gives feedback

    arguments:
    word -- word you want to check
    word_list -- list of words you want your word to compare against
    keyword arguments: 
    bad_word_list -- list of words that give custom feedback to the user. (default None)
           
    """
    if word in word_list:
        return word
    elif bad_word_list and word in bad_word_list:
        print("How dare you?!")
    else:
        print("invalid input, (check for typos)")

def game():
    computer_wins = 0
    player_wins = 0
    feedback = input("Welcome to my rock, paper scissors game, type 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors': ")
    checked_feedback = " "
    while checked_feedback != "quit":
        checked_feedback = check_word_input(feedback, words, badwords)
        computer = random.choice(["rock","paper","scissors"])
        if checked_feedback == computer:
            print("its a tie!")
        if (checked_feedback == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors') or (checked_feedback == 'paper' and computer == 'rock') or (checked_feedback == 'scissors' and computer == 'paper'):
            player_wins += 1
            print("you won!, your current score is now %d" %player_wins)
        else:
            computer_wins += 1
            print("you lost!, opponents current score is now %d" %computer_wins)
        print("type 'quit' to quit")
        checked_feedback = check_word_input(feedback, words, badwords)
        break

    print("computer score: ", computer_wins)
    print("player score: ", player_wins)
```

Comment: What is `check_word_input`?

Comment: Hi Scott, there is a comment under that function describing it. its a function that tests the input for words like "rock", "paper" or "scissors", if false prints "invalid input" if true, returns input. if profanity, returns custom message

Comment: You need a condition (if statement) around your `break` statement. There are lots of examples available for how to use break in a while loop.

Comment: you mean like : if checked_feedback == "quit":                                                          
                               Brake

Comment: Since you are writing in Python, presumably you understand that indentation affects the meaning of Python code. If you don't reproduce your indentation when you post your code on here, then your code will have different behaviour. The code in your question would not do what you describe: it would issue an indentation error. Perhaps you would like to post a [mre].

Comment: i copy pasted it the way it was, didnt know spaces were not included, lets see if i can edit this....

Comment: ok, i edited it, also included the code for checked_feedback. so it should rune fine now

Answer (score 0):

you need to change

```
print("type 'quit' to quit")
```

to

```
feedback = input("type 'quit' to quit")
```

Also I would change

```
feedback = input("Welcome to my rock, paper scissors game, type 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors': ")
```

to

```
print("Welcome to my rock, paper scissors game")
```

then at the first line of the loop  should have

```
feedback = input("Rock, paper or scissors")
```

Comment: I am not really worried about the form right now, i am trying to make the loop repeat itself until user types quit, but thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).